# integrate zapier with kommunicate

Tags: dialogflow-es, zapier, kommunicate

How to store bot data in salesfore using zapier with integration of kommunicate.
For example If a user want an appointment. Using name phone number in dialogflow stores in salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new user in Salesforce after [(Kommunicate + Zapier + Salesforce)](https://zapier.com/apps/kommunicate/integrations/salesforce) integration. Then you may need to [extract the details using Dialogflow entities](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/bot-setup#update-user-detail) and once done, it can be stored in the new user fields